# Cisco ASA 5510 multiple vlans on same interface with different security levels and routing between

Tags: firewall, cisco

Looking to setup on my 0/3 interface multiple vlans and looking to get confirmation that this will work.

```
Ethernet 0/3.1
  security-level 20
  nameif dev-dmz
  vlan 502
  ip address 172.20.2.1 255.255.255.0
Ehternet 0/3.2
  security-level 30
  nameif dev-inside
  vlan 510
  ip address 172.20.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

I would normally accomplish the above configuration by using 2 different physical interfaces but in this particular case we have a free Ethernet port and would like to configure both security levels on the same interface.

The ASA normally allows traffic from a higher security level (30) to communicate with a lower security level (20) without any additional configuration. However what makes this different from what I have normally setup is that my traffic will enter and exit out the same physical interface rather than 2 different physical interfaces.

I have read a few documents that describe routing between vlans on the same interface but all the examples I have found use the same security level and issue a command same-security-traffic intra-interface and I am not sure that this is needed since my security levels in fact are not the same.

Anything I might be missing that I need to be aware of?

I also assume I will need to enter static entry as follows

```
static (dev-inside,dev-dmz) 172.20.2.0 172.20.2.0
```

Anything else I might need?

Comment: what do you mean by " traffic will enter and exit out the same interface" ? What does matter is the logical interface (the nameif ), not the physical port. Do you have "hairpin" traffic which enter and exit the same "nameif" interface ?

Comment: Sorry should have specified that the traffic is entering/exiting out the same physical interface, however traffic is going across the sub interfaces defined above. No problem with doing this?

Comment: no, it behaves the same way, at least with 7.2.4